# Current point relative to axes Matlab without Clicking

Tags: matlab

I want to read the (x, y) position of the mouse continuously as the mouse moves around the figure, without the need for me to explicitly click at a particular position to use the GINPUT or an equivalent function.

i'm trying to use

```
C = get (gca, 'CurrentPoint');
   
 
    disp(C);
```

and with :

```
 C= get(0,'PointerLocation');
```

i get the position relative to all the screen and not the axes. How i can solve it?

But this works only if i click on the figure.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `WindowButtonMotionFcn` to any function, then the `CurrentPoint` of the axes handle gets updates as you move cursor inside the axes.

```
set(gcf,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',@(~,~)0)
get(gca,'CurrentPoint')
```

for checking it

```
printdetails=@(figh,event,ax) fprintf('%s on Fig%d | Curr Pos (x,y): (%.4f,%.4f)\n' ...
,event.EventName,event.Source.Number, ax.CurrentPoint(1,1),ax.CurrentPoint(1,2));
set(gcf,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',{printdetails,gca})
```